# What is your best practice for keeping code in sync between instances in cluster

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm using EC2 Instances with auto scaling to run production PHP/Apache.

I'm trying to find the best practice for keeping code in sync between servers using Github actions. And the fact it calls one server to pull the code.

Currently in my setup one of the servers is arbitrarily considered a master and Github push the code updates to this server. a cron job sync the code from the master to s3 and from s3 to other servers. This doesnt seem efficient.

One of the options I thought of is using shared file system (EFS) for the code but I'm not sure using EFS as the document root is a good practice.

What is the best practice for keeping code synced in multiple server scenario.

Comment: The way we recommend it (and built a tool for this) - treat your ready-to-go code as an artifact (or make it an artifact) - i.e., refer to your approved code by Git hash. Then have some authority to route artifacts to servers, i.e. say that certain Git hash is approved for all servers. Then have all servers independently pull for that specific Git hash - this way you'll ensure sync.

Comment: Thanks @taleodor . How will the servers know when to pull ?

Comment: Simplest case - create a simple cron that would run every minute and check. Sometimes you can also leverage webhooks (i.e. from GitHub). More complex agents in the end of a date revolve around same concepts. I.e. in k8s world Argo CD supports either polling or activation by webhook.

Comment: @taleodor I already use github webhook but it only calls one server.
Pulling every minute is an option. not sure if its efficient though

Comment: It's very efficient, all you need to do there is pull a value and do a simple diff. And then only do any downstream job if there is a change. I.e. this is the script we use for smaller k8s projects (we usually go with Argo for larger ones) - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-hub-integrations/blob/master/Helm-cd-with-Reliza/helm_configmap.yaml

Comment: @taleodor thanks for sharing